# Create lists dynamically (on-the-fly)

Tags: python, list

I am working with multiple lists (more than 25 lists) in a code. During the code, I am iterating for each element of the list. For instance, if I tried to assign a value to the element 'i' of the list1, it says it is not possible as the list has not been defined.

```
list1[i] = value
`name 'list1' is not defined`
```

So I have to define the 25 lists empty at the beginning of the code. **All of them will have the same length but are called differently.**

```
list1 = list(np.zeros(len(x)))
power = list(np.zeros(len(x)))
...
voltage = list(np.zeros(len(x)))
```

Additionally, I might need to create new lists for additional developments. How can I define or work with the lists without being defined as empty lists one by one?

Comment: If you have a dynamic number of lists, you should use nested lists rather than lots of different variables.

Comment: You normally build lists incrementally with `list1.append(value)`

Comment: If you need to fill the list, you can do `list1 = [0]*len(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all of your lists contained within a `defaultdict` like so, it will create new lists for you on the fly.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_len = len(x)
all_lists = defaultdict(lambda: list(np.zeros(list_len)))

all_lists[1][3] = 'hello' # creates a new list of the required length, filled with zeros, at key `1` of the `defaultdict`, and inserts the value 'hello' at index 3 in the list
all_lists['list2'][2] = 'world' # does the same thing
all_lists[1][0] = 'spam' # a list already exists at the key `1` in the `defaultdict`, so in this case the existing list at key `1` is modified, and a new list is not created. The value 'spam' is inserted at index 0 of the existing list.
```

The `defaultdict` in the example above is fed a zero-argument `lambda` function when it is constructed, instructing the `defaultdict` to always create a list of a certain length filled with zeros if a key is supplied that doesn't yet exist in the dictionary. If the key does exist, it returns the given item associated with that key, just like a normal dictionary.

The documentation for `defaultdict` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

Use nested lists.

```
lists = [[0]*len(x) for _ in range(25)]
```

Then you can later do

```
lists[n][i] =value
```

You might also consider using a pandas dataframe or numpy 2-dimensional array.

Comment: I clarified my question. I did explain that the name of the list could be differentt

Comment: If the list names are dynamic, use a dictionary containing all the lists.

Comment: But I might need 25 lists or even more. Right now I need 25, but I will continue developing the code, so I might need even more than 25 lists

Comment: That's why you should either make a list of lists or a dictionary of lists. It allows you to use any number, without having to hard-code the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create "empty" lists you can do it like this:

```
list1 = ['' for _ in range(len(x))]
```

'' if you want a string list or change it to 0 if you want an int list